# Failed to pass data from the controller to the report viewer

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, rdlc

I have created a report viewer in my .net core project. here I create windows form for creating the report. I want something like this:- first, I collect my data from the session, then these collect data pass my report viewer and want to show this report on my desktop. but when I trying this, I have found a lot of different errors.

here is my code:-

```
   public async Task<IActionResult> Print()
        {
            string mimetype = "";
            int extension = 1;
            var path = $"{this._webHostEnvironment.WebRootPath}\\Reports\\Report1.rdlc";
            Dictionary<string, string> parameters = new Dictionary<string, string>();
          

            List<Shop> shop = HttpContext.Session.Get<List<Shop>>("shop");

            for(int i=0;i<shop.Count();i++)
            {
                parameters.Add("Name", shop[i].Name);
                parameters.Add("Quantity", shop[i].Quantity);
                parameters.Add("ProductId", shop[i].Id);
                parameters.Add("Price", shop[i].Price);


            }

            
            LocalReport localReport = new LocalReport(path);
          

            var result = localReport.Execute(RenderType.Pdf, extension, parameters, mimetype);

            var r = File(result.MainStream, "application/pdf");
            return View(r);

        }
```

Report1.rdlc:-

[image]

1.Name(Text,Allow null Value,Allow multiple value) 2.ProductId(Intiger,Allow multiple values) 3.Price(Intiger,Allow multiple values) 4.(Intiger,Quantity (Allow multiple values)

I found an unexpected error:-

[image]

but I want my data report view on my desktop. what's the solution. I am still a beginner. please help.

Comment: I think to start remove the quotes from the parameters parameters.Add("Name", "shop[i].Name"); should be parameters.Add("Name", shop[i].Name);

Comment: what's the error now?

Comment: I believe that you should be using the `DataSource` property. You have declared parameters as a `Dictionary`, but then you are attempting to add multiple items with the same keys. This will not work. Research the use of `DataSource` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Part of the learning process of programming is learning to read the errors.
look where it states that you can't add the same value name 2x

Also, you are doing async Task stuff but there is no await in your code. just remove this from the method header

public IActionResult Print()
{
string mimetype = "";
int extension = 1;
var path = $"{this._webHostEnvironment.WebRootPath}\Reports\Report1.rdlc";
Dictionary<string, string> parameters = new Dictionary<string, string>();

```
List<Shop> shop = HttpContext.Session.Get<List<Shop>>("shop");

for(int i=0;i<shop.Count();i++)
{
    parameters.AddWithValue("Name", shop[i].Name);
    parameters.AddWithValue("Quantity", shop[i].Quantity);
    parameters.AddWithValue("ProductId", shop[i].Id);
    parameters.AddWithValue("Price", shop[i].Price);
}

        
LocalReport localReport = new LocalReport(path);
      

var result = localReport.Execute(RenderType.Pdf, extension, parameters, mimetype);

var r = File(result.MainStream, "application/pdf");
return View(r);
```

}

Comment: Not working. I copied and paste your code. but found an error below my "parameters".

Comment: how data type I should use for "parameters"?

Comment: I guess you have SqlParameter than you need AddWithValue, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparametercollection.addwithvalue?view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0